# Parsing multiple URLs with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get a list of hrefs from a list of ten URLs and running into trouble.

Each of these blocks work separately from each other, but, when I try to combine them, I get a list of pages 1-10 and an error. What is the proper way to go about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

#/ this prints all 10 of the URLs to pull page hrefs from.

1.upto(10) do |pagenum|
url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/page/#{pagenum}"
  puts url
end

#/ Prints out all of the hrefs. 

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath('//h2/a/@href').each do |node|
  puts node.text
end
```

Comment: Error messages provide critical clues into solving problems. You need to provide that information.

Comment: I'm getting this, I guess 'url' is undefined:   ./workfile.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `url' for main:Object (NameError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code, annotated:

```
1.upto(10) do |pagenum|
  # Create a local variable named `url`
  url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/page/#{pagenum}"

  # Print it
  puts url
end

# Open...uhm...which URL?
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

The problem is that the `url` variable is "scoped" locally to the `upto` block. It no longer exists once you exist that block. Perhaps you wanted this:

```
1.upto(10) do |pagenum|
  # Create a local variable named `url`
  url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/page/#{pagenum}"

  # Print it
  puts url

  # Print this URL
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.xpath('//h2/a/@href').each do |node|
    puts node.text
  end
end
```